# How can I combine two classes?

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have two `.txt` files. Firstly, I put the contents of `file1.txt` into string array. After that, I use another class to do the same thing for another file: `file2.txt`. I then compare contents of the two string array's against each other (specifically the words in the string arrays.) How can I combine my two classes each other?

Comment: why two different classes? You can do this in same class. Looks like homework?

Comment: modularize your code, break down into methods. Write all your file reading logic in a separate method say `getContents` which takes file name as a parameter and returns you `List<String[]>` and call that method twice from your `main` method.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO,

There is no point mixing DataInputStream and BufferedReader. A simpler pattern is to do the following

> can I compare these contents of two txt files?

```
public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
    List<String> strings1 = readFileAsList("D:\\Denemeler\\file1.txt");
    List<String> strings2 = readFileAsList("D:\\Denemeler\\file2.txt");
    compare(strings1, strings2);
}

private static void compare(List<String> strings1, List<String> strings2) {
    // TODO
}

private static List<String> readFileAsList(String name) throws IOException {
    List<String> ret = new ArrayList<String>();
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(name));
        String strLine;
        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)
            ret.add(strLine);
        return ret;
    } finally {
        if (br != null) br.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I cant use two BufferedReader in the same class for two txt files so I used another class for that

Comment: but I can't combine two of them

Comment: You can use two different buffer readers one after other or in a common method

Comment: Peter, okay I can use processFile but where can I compare these contents of two txt files?  I want to compare and show the differences for example by writing another file3.txt file

Comment: Peter firstly thank you so much, but what if I wanto to see the different words between file1.txt and file2.txt where can I see.  also thankyou the code compiles

Comment: can I use that method : <<private static void compare<< to see the different words and write these words by writing another file3.txt?

Comment: You can do whatever you want in the compare. You can use the split method to break up the words in a line.

Comment: I used split method in class cL and niL is this a write method?? how can i compare two of them line by line?

Comment: In the example I gave you have two lists, you can iterate over those lists with a loop and get the words from each line with split and compare those. Comparing two text files is actually a very complicated subject. You need to have a clear idea of exactly what it is you are trying to achieve as "comparing" could mean a lot of different things.

Answer (score 0):

You want to perform all these operations in one program. One program have only one active method `main` that will be executed when you start program.

- Read file1.txt into string array
- Read file2.txt into string array
- Compare the results

your main method will looks like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   String[] s1 = read("file1.txt");
   String[] s2 = read("file2.txt");
   compare(s1, s2);
}
```

Now you implement method `String[] read(File f)` with your own logic and comaprison in method `compare(String[] s1, String[] s2)`

Answer (score 0):

Jes 'Peter Lawrey' is right.

Java is an object oriented program we have to keep that in mind. use a common method and avoid one class.

if you want to know about the inner class have a look at this [Java Inner class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html)